# How to get all attribute names in SimpleFeature?

Tags: java, geotools

How to get all attribute names in [SimpleFeature](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeature.html)?

I find no appropriate method. I can get all attributes by `getAttributes`, but I will loose names information. I can get attribute by name with `getAttribute`, but I should know a name first.

So where is the method to enumerate names or what is the reason it absent?

Answer (score 2):

You may try [SimpleFeature.getFeatureType()](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeature.html#getFeatureType%28%29) which gets you a meta description [SimpleFeatureType](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeatureType.html). On this object you may use some of the descriptor methods, e.g. [getAttributeDescriptors()](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeatureType.html#getAttributeDescriptors%28%29). The last method lists the attribute meta descriptors and they are the point from where you get the name: [AttributeDescriptor.getLocalName()](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/type/AttributeDescriptor.html#getLocalName%28%29).

Another way is [SimpleFeature.getProperties()](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/ComplexAttribute.html#getProperties%28%29) which yields a collection of [Properties](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/Property.html) where you can call [getName()](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/Property.html#getName%28%29). Compare to the descriptions of the various `g/setAttribute*` of `SimpleFeature` which document that `g/setAttribute*` are shortcuts to the corresponding `g/setProperty*` methods.

Be aware of namespaces.